# Flutter Google Maps flutter polyline points not working

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]

I'm trying to create route from point A to B, following the package example of flutter_polyline_points from pub.dev but it draws polyline like this. please help.

I've been doing this for three days straight now i need help.

attached are the code concerning the polyline:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add your code please?

Comment: Can you show the data from "getRouteBetweenCoordinates" and if they are correctly formatted. Are you trying this on the web (https://github.com/Dammyololade/flutter_polyline_points/issues/40)?

Comment: Yes I'm trying this on web. I saw the github link but I'm unsure how to implement it on mine. how do I get the (String encoded) parameter in the function

Comment: I guess, you could fork the repo and change this file https://github.com/Dammyololade/flutter_polyline_points/blob/master/lib/src/network_util.dart by using the function given in my previous link.

Comment: thank you for this but i think this is beyond a beginner like me.

Comment: Someone already did it, change your pubspec to use this https://github.com/Lone-Wolf17/flutter_polyline_points/tree/master
flutter_polyline_points: 
    git: https://github.com/Lone-Wolf17/flutter_polyline_points/tree/master

Try if this solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is described here https://github.com/Dammyololade/flutter_polyline_points/issues/40

The package is not up to date and a PR to fix it is waiting for some times (https://github.com/Dammyololade/flutter_polyline_points/pull/68)

You should use this repo (or better, fork it to your account) while the PR is still open.
Change your pubspec to use it

```
flutter_polyline_points: 
    git: github.com/Lone-Wolf17/flutter_polyline_points/tree/master
```

Comment: I tried to add that but it says 

stderr: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\flo\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\git\cache\master-c76a3075e6f14c4840af9de594cf48cbddba45d0'...
fatal: 'C:/Users/flo/StudioProjects/nextfarm/github.com/Lone-Wolf17/flutter_polyline_points/tree/master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: If you are using a local entry, don't use "git:" but "path:" in your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: what if i want to use online entry

Comment: With a repo you created?

Comment: I tried to fork the repo, still not working.

Comment: It's seems more like an auth issue, can you clone it with a simple "git clone" somewhere?